# Racket URL dispatch

Tags: scheme, webserver, url-routing, racket

I'm trying to hook up URL dispatch with Racket (formerly PLT Scheme). I've taken a look at the tutorial and the server documentation. I can't figure out how to route requests to the same servlets.

Specific example:

```
#lang scheme

(require web-server/servlet)
(require web-server/dispatch)
(provide/contract (start (request? . -> . response/c)))

(define (start request)
  (blog-dispatch request))

(define-values (blog-dispatch blog-url)
  (dispatch-rules
   (("") list-posts)
   (("posts" (string-arg)) review-post)
   (("archive" (integer-arg) (integer-arg)) review-archive)
   (else list-posts)))

(define (list-posts req) `(list-posts))
(define (review-post req p) `(review-post ,p))
(define (review-archive req y m) `(review-archive ,y ,m))

(require web-server/servlet-env)
(serve/servlet start
               #:launch-browser? #t
               #:quit? #f
               #:listen-ip #f
               #:port 8080
               #:extra-files-paths (list (build-path "js")
                                         (build-path "css"))
               #:servlet-path "")
```

Assuming the above code, `localhost:8080/` goes to a page that says "list-posts". Going to `localhost:8080/posts/test` goes to a Racket "file not found" page (I'd expect it to go to a page that says "review-post test").

It feels like I'm missing something small and obvious. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you've written is not a whole program, so I cannot debug it.

Here is a program with annotations that does what you want, probably:

```
#lang scheme ; specify the right language
; include the correct libraries
(require web-server/servlet
         ; this one gets "serve/servlet"
         web-server/servlet-env)

(define (start request)
  (blog-dispatch request))

(define-values (blog-dispatch blog-url)
  (dispatch-rules
   (("") list-posts)
   (("posts" (string-arg)) review-post)
   (("archive" (integer-arg) (integer-arg)) review-archive)
   (else list-posts)))

(define (list-posts req) `(list-posts))
(define (review-post req p) `(review-post ,p))
(define (review-archive req y m) `(review-archive ,y ,m))

; starts a web server where...
(serve/servlet start ; answers requests
               #:servlet-path "" ; is the default URL
               #:port 8080 ; is the port
               #:servlet-regexp #rx"") ; is a regexp decide
                                       ; if 'start' should
                                       ; handle the request
```

Because the functions `list-posts`, `review-post`, and `review-archive` don't return sensible xexpr encodings of HTML, you'll have to view source to see them right.

Please feel free to email me directly or email the PLT Scheme mailing list. (Note: We are renaming PLT Scheme to "Racket" so you may see that when you post.)

Jay McCarthy

Comment: Yup. I was missing the servlet-regexp parameter. As I suspected; something small and obvious. Thank you for helping me out.